# strtoimax doesnt throw EINVAL errno on bad conversion with WSL

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am creating a tool similar to the history command in Linux and am developing on the windows subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu). I am currently trying to parse my command argument and filter out an invalid input by the user. The documentation for `strtoimax` says that the `EINVAL` feature is not available on all platforms and I suspect that WSL does not support it. Is there any way I can distinguish between a true "0" input and a 0 that origins from a conversion, without having to check against the original string with `cmpstr`?

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Too many arguments: %d", argc);
    }

    if (argc == 2) {
        const char* errstr;
        errno = 0;
        char** cptr;
        int conversionResult = strtoimax(argv[1], cptr, 0);
        if (errno == 0) {
            displayHistory(conversionResult);
        } else {
            switch (errno) {
                case ERANGE:
                    char buf[200];
                    snprintf(buf, 200, "The given amount exceeds %d", INT_MAX);
                    displayError(buf);
                    break;
                case EINVAL: //This does not work as intended...
                    displayError("The given amount must be a positive integer.");
                    break;
                default:
                    displayError("An unknown error occured while parsing the argument.");
            }
        }

    }

    if (argc == 1) { displayHistory(50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

As requested, here are some examples of inputs:

```
Command: ./a.out 40
Output: Displaying 40 elements...
(More stuff follows, but is irrelevant, the 40 is correctly interpreted)

Command: ./a.out gsgsg
Actual Output: Displaying 0 elements...
Expected: ios_history: The given amount must be a positive integer
```

Comment: It looks weird that the value of uninitialized non-static local variable `cptr` is passed to `strtoimax`.

Comment: `EINVAL` is a POSIX extension (see [this reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoimax.html)). Any envornment that conforms to the POSIX.1-2017 standard should be able to handle it.

Comment: @MikeCAT Ignore my bad c skills, I am a total beginner with c. Previously I just passed NULL as the second argument, I thought maybe the null buffer was interfering with the validity check or something....

Comment: `char** cptr` -> `char* cptr` and `strtoimax(argv[1], cptr, 0)` -> `strtoimax(argv[1], &cptr, 0)`. Or `strtoimax(argv[1], NULL, 0)` and drop `char** cptr` alltogether as you don't use it. There may be more issues.

Comment: The last thing you wrote was the expression I originally used, I will return to it. Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: If you pass the address of a `char* cptr;` then `cptr` will point to the character after the last character that was converted. You can use this in combination with the pointer to the input string to check the string in case of result 0. With a value 0, I would expect `cptr` to be different from `argv[1]` and the character before it to be `'\0'`, otherwise I would assume an error.

Comment: @Bodo you should make this an answer. Actually the best approach is to make a function like e.g. `bool GetNumericArgument(const char *arg, int *number)` that returns false if the argument was anything else than a string representing decimal number.

Comment: Use `char* cptr;` and `strtoimax(argv[1], &cptr, 0);` as described above. Then immediately before the `if (errno == 0)`, add the following to check for a bad subject sequence: `if (errno == 0 && cptr == argv[1]) {` `errno = EINVAL;` `}`. You could also add a test for an invalid terminating sequence. E.g. `if (errno == 0 && (cptr == argv[1] || *cptr != '\0')) {` will check for either an invalid subject sequence or a non-empty terminating sequence. (You could modify that test if you want to allow the terminating sequence to start with a delimiter character.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `strtoimax()` may report any information by setting `errno` to `EINVAL` is a POSIX extension.  A POSIX-conforming implementation will definitely do this if an unsupported base is specified, but [the spec says this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoimax.html) about the case you're interested in:

> If no conversion could be performed, zero shall be returned and
> `errno` may be set to [EINVAL].

Note the "may".  Even conforming POSIX implementations are not required to report a conversion failure via `errno`.

Note also that a failure to convert is when no digits at all are consumed from the source.  This is not the same thing as the whole string being converted.

The usual way to distinguish between successful and unsuccessful conversion is to look around the location to which the end pointer reported by the function points.  If it differs from the start of the string and the previous character is a digit then a conversion has been performed.  If it points to a string terminator then the full input has been consumed.

Consider this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// ...

void convert_string(const char *str) {
    char *end;
    errno = 0;  // clear any errno hanging around from previous calls
    intmax_t result = strtointmax(str, &end, 0);
    int conversion_errno = errno; // capture the errno value after strtointmax

    if (end != str) {
        // successful conversion

        if ((result == INTMAX_MAX || result == INTMAX_MIN)
                && (conversion_errno == ERANGE)) {
            // unrepresentable result
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrepresentable as an intmax_t: '%s'\n", str);
        } 

        printf("Computed result: %" PRIdMAX "\n", result);

        if (*end) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Trailing characters are present: '%s'\n", end);
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not a valid decimal integer: '%s'\n", str)
    }
}
```

Note well that as a general rule, you should not test `errno` without any indication that it has something to tell you.  That indication is usually that a function call returns -1 to indicate an error, *and* it is documented to set `errno` under those conditions.

Note also that nothing in the standard library ever sets `errno` to 0, but things may set `errno` to other values even on success, so if you're going to ignore the above general rule then it is essential for you to manually zero `errno` immediately before the function call to test.  Also, you need to be careful to avoid another function call changing the `errno` value you want to monitor.

The `strtoint*` functions are a special case here, because they don't provide an unambiguous error signal.  The above code demonstrates a way to test all the possibilities.

Comment: In general things may set `errno` to non-zero values even on success, but POSIX specifies that the `strto*` functions do not change the value of `errno` on success. (Really, the C specification ought to specify that too, IMHO.)

Comment: Is `&& isdigit(end[-1])` really required? It seems that wouldn't work when base is 0 or in the range 11 to 36.

Comment: @IanAbbott, you are right, it is sufficient to test that `end != str`.  No test of `end[-1]` is required (edited).  Some versions of the function's documentation are less than clear about that -- in particular about what `end` may be set to if the input string contains leading whitespace, which is ordinarily accepted and ignored by the function, but no digits immediately following.  I have convinced myself that the more authoritative sources are clear that if no conversion is performed then the end pointer is set to point to the first character of the input.